# How to get index at which TableRow is at in a TableLayout?

Tags: java, android, layout-inflater

So I'm currently creating a little reminders app, you create your reminder, it adds to a TableRow to a TableLayout, which is the child of a ScrollView. Everything is pretty basic.

What I wanted to do is when I add the TableRow to the TableLayout with `LayoutInflater`, how do I set a tag on that TableRow, and how would I get the information stored in that TableLayout later in my code?

Current Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private TableLayout reminderTableScrollView;

    Button deleteReminderButton;

    Toast remindersToast;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        reminderTableScrollView = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.reminderTableScrollView);

        deleteReminderButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        deleteReminderButton.setOnClickListener(deleteClickListener);
    }

    private void goToEnterData() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReminderData.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent returnIntent) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                String title = returnIntent.getStringExtra("title");
                String description = returnIntent.getStringExtra("description");
                String hour = returnIntent.getStringExtra("hour");
                String minute = returnIntent.getStringExtra("minute");
                String amPm = returnIntent.getStringExtra("amPm");

                Log.d("Debug", String.valueOf(list));
                Log.d("Debug", hour + ":" + minute);

                inflate(title, description, hour, minute, amPm);
            }
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                displayToast(new Toast(this), "Reminder canceled");
            }
        }
    }

    private void inflate(String text, String description, String hour, String minute, String amPm) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View reminder = inflator.inflate(R.layout.reminder_layout, null);

        TextView reminderListTextView = (TextView) reminder.findViewById(R.id.reminderListTextView);
        reminderListTextView.setText(text);

        TextView reminderListTimeTextView = (TextView) reminder.findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);
        reminderListTimeTextView.setText(hour + ":" + minute + ((amPm == "0") ? " AM" : " PM"));

        reminderTableScrollView.addView(reminder);

        Log.d("Debug", String.valueOf(reminderTableScrollView.getTag(0)));
    }
```

ReminderData.java

```
public class ReminderData extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText titleEditText;
    EditText descriptionEditText;
    EditText hourTimeEditText;
    EditText minuteTimeEditText;

    Spinner spinner;

    Button enterButton;

    Toast toast;

    SQLiteDatabase myDB;

    String title;
    String description;

    int spinnerPosition;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminder_data);

        titleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleEditText);
        descriptionEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descriptionEditText); 

        hourTimeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hourTimeEditText);
        minuteTimeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minuteTimeEditText);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ampm_spinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(spinnerItemSelectedListener);

        enterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enterButton);
        enterButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private OnItemSelectedListener spinnerItemSelectedListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            spinnerPosition = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    };

    private void returnData(String titleString, String descriptionString, String hour, String minute, String amPm) {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("title", titleString);
        returnIntent.putExtra("description", descriptionString);
        returnIntent.putExtra("hour", hour);
        returnIntent.putExtra("minute", minute);
        returnIntent.putExtra("amPm", amPm);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
```

**Sorry for the massive jumbles of code, usually I try to keep it short and people ask for more code**

**Edit:** I removed the unnecessary coding

Comment: Sorry, but could you just show _relevant_ code? I know people want to see code, but they want to see the code that pertains to the problem (not all the debug and import code). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This, and not lots of code, is what people really want to see (I realize it's sometimes hard to know how much code is right).

Comment: @Nateowami Well, sorry I was thinking that because my code had a ton of references to other parts of the code, I should add all the code. Also, since I thought I would have to re-write most of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I wanted to do is when I add the TableRow to the TableLayout with
>   LayoutInflater, how do I set a tag on that TableRow, and how would I
>   get the information stored in that TableLayout later in my code?

You can set the index of a TableRow as the tag to it. Doing like this in your inflate(String text, String description, String hour, String minute, String amPm) method:

```
int index = reminderTableScrollView.getChildCount();
reminder.setTag(index);
reminderTableScrollView.addView(reminder);
```

And then retrieve the index like this:

```
int index = (Integer)reminder.getTag();
```

**Update:**

According to your comment, what you want can be achieved by setting an OnClickListener to each TableRow like this:

```
    int index = reminderTableScrollView.getChildCount();
    reminder.setTag(index);
    reminder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            // The View you get here is actually the reminder
            int index = (Integer)reminder.getTag();
            // Now you have the index, you can do what you want.
        }
    });
    reminderTableScrollView.addView(reminder);
```

Comment: Could you add these indexes to an array? An array which I could get all of them later in my code?

Comment: @YayCoding That make no sense, what do you want to do with those indices? Why do you want them in an Array?

Comment: I want the user to be able to click on them and view more info about them, I need to use an array and add OnClickListeners to each of them. Then get the info from the tag that is set. Hopefully that made sense

Comment: Thank you very much, one last thing, with the tag set and everything, this does allow me to get TextViews, etc. from the TableRow right?

Comment: @YayCoding You actually don't need that tag to get TextViews from the TableRow. Since you have the reminder in your onClick() method, you can get TextViews by using reminder.findViewById() just as what you do in your code now.

Comment: Oh, I see. And this will dynamically work for each and every reminder even if I had 10? (e.g. 2 reminders, one with title of 'Eat' and another with 'Gym,' code will dynamically get each TextView?)

Comment: @YayCoding Yes, the code works for many reminders more than 10, though it does have a upper limitation, it is enough for you.